# Simple Database Schema for a tech blog

Tags: database, schema, laravel-5.4

I am building a simple tech blog and this is my database.
Because I don't really have a lot of experience I am looking to get some feedback if its an OK schema.

[image: Database Schema]

I will have 5 categories: Computer, mobile , laptop , tablet and General.

- For users I will only have an admin to begin with and maybe I will add users later.
- User will only be able to comment/share on the posts nothing more.
  Only admins will be able to create posts etc.
- Guests will only be able to browse the site and share posts.
- I would like to add a feature to be able to count how many shares have been made for a specific post but later.
- Also I might add sub categories to each category (for this I think that I need another table to track those).

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view, you should add a `comments` table; in your database a Post can have only one comment.

Comments should have this fields at minimum: `id, body, post_id, user_id`, because they belong to a Post and to a User.

In the `posts` table add fields: `user_id and category_id` because each post belongs to a User and to a Category; and remove the comment field because a post can have many comments.